# Code no longer working in OS4.3 but fine in 5.0 (used to work fine)

Tags: ios, xcode, debugging

Weird error.  My code was written in Xcode 3, and it loaded fine in 4.4 without errors.

Recently, it started not working in OS 4.3 or below, but fine in 5.0 and 5.1.  I've done a few weeks of updating my app, so I have no idea where it went out of whack (I was using the current simulator 5.1 when testing, so I didn't even think to try the others after each trial).

Here is my error log, but I can't figure out whats causing the crash. It should note that I get "location services not available" when launching in 4.3 or below, but not in 5.0 and above.  It crashes about the time I try to load a view that has a table.  Here is my debugger info... any ideas?

```
> 2012-09-03 05:43:39.582 Diners[7811:12203] [-[MapViewController viewDidLoad] /Users/user/Documents/Source Code/Working Projects/Diners/Classes/MapViewController.m:48] 
bootstrap_look_up failed (44e)
2012-09-03 05:43:42.997 Diners[7811:12203] [-[StripClubsAppDelegate i3fSplashViewBrickDidRemoveFromSuperview:] /Users/user/Documents/Source Code/Working Projects/Diners/Classes/StripClubsAppDelegate.m:77] 
2012-09-03 05:43:49.883 Diners[7811:12203] -[UITapGestureRecognizer initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5fe01b0
2012-09-03 05:43:49.950 Diners[7811:12203] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITapGestureRecognizer initWithCoder:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x5fe01b0'
*** Call stack at first throw:
(
    0   CoreFoundation    0x014585a9 __exceptionPreprocess + 185
    1   libobjc.A.dylib   0x01205313 objc_exception_throw + 44
    2   CoreFoundation    0x0145a0bb -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 187
    3   CoreFoundation    0x013c9966 ___forwarding___ + 966
    4   CoreFoundation    0x013c9522 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 50
    5   UIKit             0x0061c9fd UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592
    6   UIKit             0x0061d6ac -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398
    7   UIKit             0x0053293e -[UIRuntimeConnection initWithCoder:] + 153
    8   UIKit             0x00532ee7 -[UIRuntimeEventConnection initWithCoder:] + 64
    9   UIKit             0x0061c9fd UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 2592
    10  UIKit             0x0061c2f5 UINibDecoderDecodeObjectForValue + 792
    11  UIKit             0x0061d6ac -[UINibDecoder decodeObjectForKey:] + 398
    12  UIKit             0x00531c36 -[UINib instantiateWithOwner:options:] + 804
    13  UIKit             0x00533ab7 -[NSBundle(UINSBundleAdditions) loadNibNamed:owner:options:] + 168
    14  UIKit             0x003e9628 -[UIViewController _loadViewFromNibNamed:bundle:] + 70
    15  UIKit             0x003e7134 -[UIViewController loadView] + 120
    16  UIKit             0x003e700e -[UIViewController view] + 56
    17  UIKit             0x003e5482 -[UIViewController contentScrollView] + 42
    18  UIKit             0x003f5f25 -[UINavigationController _computeAndApplyScrollContentInsetDeltaForViewController:] + 48
    19  UIKit             0x003f4555 -[UINavigationController _layoutViewController:] + 43
    20  UIKit             0x003f5870 -[UINavigationController _startTransition:fromViewController:toViewController:] + 524
    21  UIKit             0x003f032a -[UINavigationController _startDeferredTransitionIfNeeded] + 266
    22  UIKit             0x003f7562 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:transition:forceImmediate:] + 932
    23  UIKit             0x003f01c4 -[UINavigationController pushViewController:animated:] + 62
    24  Diners            0x00002c83 -[MapViewController goToListByState] + 275
    25  UIKit             0x003374fd -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 119
    26  UIKit             0x003c7799 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    27  UIKit             0x003c9c2b -[UIControl(Internal) _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 527
    28  UIKit             0x003c8a1c -[UIControl touchesBegan:withEvent:] + 277
    29  UIKit             0x0035bd41 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 395
    30  UIKit             0x0033cc37 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 447
    31  UIKit             0x00341f2e _UIApplicationHandleEvent + 7576
    32  GraphicsServices  0x01a2e992 PurpleEventCallback + 1550
    33  CoreFoundation    0x01439944 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 52
    34  CoreFoundation    0x01399cf7 __CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 215
    35  CoreFoundation    0x01396f83 __CFRunLoopRun + 979
    36  CoreFoundation    0x01396840 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 208
    37  CoreFoundation    0x01396761 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 97
    38  GraphicsServices  0x01a2d1c4 GSEventRunModal + 217
    39  GraphicsServices  0x01a2d289 GSEventRun + 115
    40  UIKit             0x00345c93 UIApplicationMain + 1160
    41  Diners            0x0000203d main + 125
    42  Diners            0x00001fb5 start + 53
)
terminate called throwing an exception(lldb)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that you add a gesture recognizer using interface builder, this feature is only available for ios5 and more.

Comment: Ahhh... that explains it.  So what would be the easiest way to keep my "swipes" but still be ios 4 compatible?

Comment: You could add them programmatically